# Chef recipe search engine

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to search for a Chef recipe that will install the Aptana Studio 3 binary and similar binary downloading and compiling procedures like one for nginx, but when I google for Chef recipes I get a bunch of five star restaurants and stuff.  Is there a trick to searching for recipes or a dedicated search engine for Chef Recipes by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "opscode" to the front of all your searches :)

You can also checkout the community site: http://community.opscode.com

Disclaimer: I work for Opscode.